# Mark a Date as "Overdue 10-13 days" in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I currently have a sheet that looks at column "I" and displays in column "J" if the date is:
"Due in 8 days"
"Due in 7 days"
"Due in 6 days"
"Due in 5 days"
"Due in 4 days"
"Due in 3 days"
"Due in 2 days"
"Due Tomorrow"
"Due Yesterday"
"Due Today"
"Overdue within 7 days"
"Overdue within 14 Days"
"Overdue within 21 days"
"Overdue more than 30 days"

Formula:

```
=IF(I14=TODAY()+8, "Due in 8 days", 
 IF(I14=TODAY()+7, "Due in 7 days", 
 IF(I14=TODAY()+6, "Due in 6 days", 
 IF(I14=TODAY()+5, "Due in 5 days", 
 IF(I14=TODAY()+4, "Due in 4 days", 
 IF(I14=TODAY()+3, "Due in 3 days", 
 IF(I14=TODAY()+2, "Due in 2 days", 
 IF(I14=TODAY()+1, "Due Tomorrow", 
 IF(I14=TODAY()-1, "Due Yesterday", 
 IF(I14=TODAY(), "Due Today", 
 IF(I14>TODAY()-7, "Overdue within 7 days", 
 IF(I14>TODAY()-14, "Overdue 14-17 Days", 
 IF(I14>TODAY()-21, "Overdue 20-23 days", "Overdue 30-33 days")))))))))))))
```

THE QUESTION: What formula can I use to find:

"Due 4-7 days" and "Overdue 10-13 days"

Comment: You'd need to change the formula.

Comment: Correct.  But I can't find an example formula for something like "Overdue 10-13 days".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following both comments by @Matt

> You'd need to change the formula.

and @Terry

> Correct. But I can't find an example formula for something like "Overdue 10-13 days"

You should follow this pattern

```
=IF(AND(I14<TODAY()-14,I14>TODAY()-17), "Overdue 14-17 Days","rest_if_formula")
```

***Do** try figuring it out yourself (you can do it)*

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to get code written for you for free, and please don't turn it into one.

Comment: I agree with you @matt and thank you for your comment. Just giving guidance to the right track.